# What is a No Error Error in Oracle

Tags: plsql, toad

I am getting this message when trying to compile an Oracle Function:

```
[Warning] ORA-24344: success with compilation error
No errors (1: 0): Warning: compiled but with compilation errors
```

This is the entire error message. How can it be compiled with errors when it actually says that there are no errors?

Thanks,
--Jacob

Answer (score 1):

What tool are you using?  In SQL/Plus, type

```
show errors
```

to show the errors.

In Toad, click on the Messages tab on the bottom of the screen.

You may need ALTER ANY PROCEDURE permission?  Not real sure of this one.

Comment: I am using TOAD. The above text was copied from the messages tab.

Comment: not too familiar with TOAD but you probably have an option to get a command window or something like that. In that window, use `show errors` and you should see the detail.

Answer (score 0):

In Schema Browser:

- navigate to Functions node
- click that function's name
- on the right hand side pane, pick the "Errors" tab
- it'll show you which errors were met while compiling the function

  - it will also show which line and column contains the error
  - if you click (or double click? Can't remember) the error itself, it'll lead you to the "Source" tab and position cursor to the erroring position